# How to use this RegEx from my JavaScript code in PHP to preserve UTF-8 chars while removing symbols?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, utf-8

My goal is to remove only symbol characters like #$^&%()'"!,.? etc. and whitespace from my string while preserving every other UTF-8 character, numbers and regular characters. I got this working on the JavaScript front-end but fail to make it work on the server in PHP. Here's my code:

RegEx:

```
/[-'`~!@#$%^&*()_|+=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/\s]/gi
```

Front-End (JavaScript):

```
var accountName = accountNameRaw.replace(/[-'`~!@#$%^&*()_|+=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/\s]/gi, '');
```

Server (PHP):

```
$cleanName = preg_replace('/[-'`~!@#$%^&*()_|+=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/\s]/gi', '', $r["accountname"]);
```

All I get as output on the front-end is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` due to the malformed response (it expects JSON). When I change the PHP regex part to `/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/` it works just fine but it also removes my UTF-8 chars like üäéëï etc. :(...

Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks a lot!

Comment: How does it pertain the JSON response? Why would `<` be a problem in there? Aren't you using `json_encode()` ?

Comment: No, I'm using `json_encode()` before I send my response, but looking at the syntax highlighting of the regex there seems to be a problem with un-escaped quotes. But even if I escape them with a `\` it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleaned-up version of the PHP replacement:

```
$cleanName = preg_replace('/[][\'`~!@#$%^&*()_|+=?;:\'",.<>{}\\\\\/\s-]+/', '', $r["accountname"]);
```

**Explanation**

- The `+` at the end cuts down on the number of replacements in case you have several special chars in a row.
- In PHP, many characters don't need to be escaped in a character class
- `preg_replace` replaces all matches: there is no `g` flag

Comment: FYI: Added optimization and explanation. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this incredibly quick, thorough and working answer :)!

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things when transcoding your regex to PCRE syntax in PHP:

- There is no `/g` flag in PHP.
- The triple backslash `\\\` before the `/` delimiter will end up as `\\` in the regex, and won't escape the `/`.  Use either just `\/` or `\\/` - better yet an entirely different regex delimiter.
- You did indeed forget to escape your `"` within the charclass.
- And you may wish to apply the `/u` Unicode flag.

Alternatively use `[\pL]` to allow Unicode letters, or just `[[:punct:]]` to strip punctuation.